# Does WebRTC work on Windows Phone UWP?

Tags: javascript, android, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app, webrtc

I'm working on [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/) using Visual Studio 2015 to create audio peer connection. It works fine when I deployed the solution on both *Android* and local machine (Microsoft Edge on PC), but on *Windows phone* has an error which said that `RTCSessionDescription() is undefined`. It occurs in `adapter.js` file.

Does WebRTC support on Windows Phone?

**Note:**

1. Edge on Windows phone version is 25.10586.0.0
2. Edge HTML on Windows phone version is 13.10586
3. The device is Lumia 730